# (YouTube API v3) GET request to Search.list returns empty responses

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a python program to retrieve information (video id, video author, etc) on all videos that show up as result to a search (**q="cancer+vlog"**).

I have the following **GET** request that runs first:

```
  results = youtube.search().list(
            order="relevance",
            part="snippet",
            publishedAfter="2015-06-01T00:00:00Z",
            maxResults=50,
            type="video",
            q="cancer+vlog"
            ).execute()
```

After processing the first batch of **results** (up to 50 videos as specified in maxResults=50), I check to see if **results** contains the **nextPageToken** key. If so, then I run another **GET** request with the **nextPageToken** from the previous run:

```
  results = youtube.search().list(
            pageToken = results["nextPageToken"],
            order="relevance",
            part="snippet",
            publishedAfter="2015-06-01T00:00:00Z",
            maxResults=50,
            type="video",
            q="cancer+vlog"
            ).execute()
```

Since I want to retrieve *all* the videos from my search result, I repeat the **GET** request with the **pageToken** until **results** does not contain the **nextPageToken** key. This seems to work fine until the program reaches about ~600 videos, then the server continues giving 200 responses without any video information, essentially an empty **results["items"]** array (even though there is about 600K video to be retrieved). I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this?

I didn't want to make this post any longer, but if anyone is interested in the entire code base, it's here: http://pastebin.com/vXeiQ6cz

Comment: Who the dump, give down vote, without any comment, at least give a reason.

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680377/819764

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you make a server load on youtube data api, officially, youtube does not use this api, it is for other users like us, Python is a server side language, and by your script, you send too many query, or get request to the api, that why it shows, this type of error. I am not a python developer. I am php guy, in php there is a function sleep to delay execution for some time, if there is something like that you can use it. Hope it helps you.